# "Connection is already closed." error with python WebSocket client

Tags: python, websocket

I've been trying to use the python websocket-client module to receive and store continuous updates from an exchange. Generally, the script will run smoothly for a day or so before raising the following error: `websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection is already closed`.

I've looked at the websocket-client source code and apparently the error is being raised in line 92 by the code `if not bytes_:`. Furthermore, the `WebSocketConnectionClosedException` is supposed to be raised `"If remote host closed the connection or some network error happened"`.

Can anybody tell me why this is happening, and what I could do to stop or handle it.

Comment: Show us some code please.

Comment: It means that someone closed the connection. Can you just re-establish it? I think you'd need that for resiliency anyway.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: I would like to know how to reproduce this error because this has cost me a lot of money. I think adding a check like:

    
   
            try:
                ws.close()
            except:
                pass
            finally:
                self.connect()

would work but idk yet

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the remote host closed the connection. You cannot stop it. You can handle it by re-connecting.

People running web servers will implement automatic cleanup to get rid of potentially stale connections. Closing a connection that's been open for 24 hours sounds like a sensible approach. And there's no harm done, because if the client is still interested, it can re-establish the connection. That's also useful to re-authenticate the client, if authentication is required.

On second thought, it might be a network disconnect as well. Some DSL providers used to disconnect and re-assign a new IP every 24 hours, to prevent users from running permanent services on temporarily assigned IP addresses. Don't know if they still do that.